# How to view data saved in android database(SQLite)?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am able to view the database from eclipse(from **file explorer**), but I want to view the whole detail, I mean the data that I have inserted, which I am unable.  And my complete Android installation has made on **F Drive**.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can access this folder using the DDMS for your Emulator. you can't access this location on a real device unless you have a rooted device.

You can view Table structure and Data in Eclipse. Here are the steps

1. Install SqliteManagerPlugin for Eclipse. Jump to step 5 if you already have it.
2. Download the *.jar file from [here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)
3. Put the *.jar file into the folder eclipse/dropins/
4. Restart eclipse
5. In the top right of eclipse, click the DDMS icon
6. Select the proper emulator in the left panel
7. In the File Explorer tab on the main panel, go to /data/data/[YOUR.APP.NAMESPACE]/databases
8. Underneath the DDMS icon, there should be a new blue icon of a Database light up when you select your database. Click it and you will see a Questoid Sqlite Manager tab open up to view your data.

*Note: If the database doesn't light up, it may be because your database doesn't have a *.db file extension. Be sure your database is called [DATABASE_NAME].db

*Note: if you want to use a DB without .db-Extension:

1. Download this Questoid SqLiteBrowser: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.questoid/com.questoid.sqlitebrowser_1.2.0.jar.zip
2. Unzip and put it into eclipse/dropins (not Plugins)

Check this for more [information](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

Comment: @soorya good ans but jar file not properly installing. it showing blur icon and it is not clickable in DDMS. why?

Comment: did you put it in the eclipse plugin folder.....i can't understand why its not working

Comment: @YESi placed  com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar file in eclipse/plugins  "It showing blur icon(In your article u showed with red arrow mark. there database icon was color no? it is rest in my case! ) and it is not clickable also in DDMS " .and one thing im using Helios version.

Comment: first you go to the data->data->Your Package-->then click the db file, then it will enable

Comment: @soorya yeah! right.. but it opens only for .db extension my sqlite file is not .db extension. without renaming what can i do ?

Comment: updated Link to download: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/

Comment: Download the *.jar files from here "http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/"

Comment: Updated the answer to contain new link.

Comment: Does this require me to root the device? I don't think it's possible to go into the data/data directory without that...

Comment: no..you cant see the database through device..this is d case of simulator

Comment: Device must be rooted in order to access data/data directory.

Comment: /data is not present in my phone. How can i do that?

Comment: You can only view /data on your physical phone if it is rooted.  But you can view /data on a running emulator.

Comment: any idea how to in ADT

Answer (score 6):

Dowlnoad sqlite manager and install it from [Here](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).Open the sqlite file using that browser.

Comment: This manager seems to have a problem opening the contacts db, I'm not sure if that also applies to other Android sqlite dbs. The firefox addon [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) did the job for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

1. Download the [Sqlite Manager jar file](http://www.coderzheaven.com/android1/com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar) here.
2. Add it to your **eclipse > dropins** Directory.
3. **Restart** eclipse.
4. **Launch** the compatible emulator or device
5. **Run** your application.
6. Go to **Window > Open Perspective > DDMS >**
7. Choose the running device.
8. Go to **File Explorer** tab.
9. Select the directory called **databases** under your application's package.
10. Select the **.db** file under the **database** directory.
11. Then click **Sqlite manager icon** like this [image: Sqlite manager icon].
12. Now you're able to see the .db file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to copy the actual SQLite database file to your desktop, you can use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) tools to browse the data.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the firefox plugin(SQLLite Manager) if you always use firefox.

Here is the [link](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/)

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8925968/621951 This is the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Download SQLite Manager
2. Go to your DDMS tab in Eclipse
3. Go to the File Explorer --> data --> data --> "Your Package Name" --> pull file from device 4. Open file in SQLite Manager.
5. View data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open DDMS than in DATA>DATA>"Select your package like com.example.foo"> than select your database folder than pull that data 
in eclipse you can see the pull an push icon on top right side ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to download anything, you can use sqlite3 tool which is provided with adb :

[Examining sqlite3 databases from a remote shell](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite)

and :

[Command Line Shell For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)