# Is there any SQLite Client on Eclipse to analyse the database used in Android Application?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a android application which i am developing using eclipse. I have a database in this application to which I cam make inserts and updates etc. Everything working fine so far. But I to check the status of a table at any given instance I need to do a query using the java code to see what is the status. Status i mean the row contents in my tables. I use the below code:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(MY_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_TITLE },
                whereclause, null, null, null, sortOrder);
```

I have some experience working on windows applications where I know the back end of the application can be accessed by using the SQL Server Management Studio and writing the queries directly like, select * from MY_TABLE, will give the results

I suppose there should be a similar application for SQLite or atleast a Eclipse plugin to do this job easy for me. Just to run any queries on my application table. But I have very little idea of SQLite so some one plase let me know the details of this. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762389/how-to-view-data-saved-in-android-databasesqlite

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. Can you please mark it as a answer so that I an accept it as the answer. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: Hi Rasel. I see the definitions of the table fine. But the data is always empty. Is it that I cannot see it when running the application? or is it any other problem?

Comment: See http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to view data saved in android database(SQLite)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762389/how-to-view-data-saved-in-android-databasesqlite)