# Not able to open database file in SQLite manager plugin for eclipse?

Tags: android, sqlite

I downloaded the jar file and placed it in `/plugins` directory. Restarted eclipse as asked for eclipse to load new plugin. Opened file explorer and navigated to /package.name/databases/file.db but not able to open it in the plugin. It appears unclickable. What to do here? Check screenshot. [image]

Comment: whats the name of the plugin ?

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/

Answer (score 10):

From the emulator unistall the app.
Then in the code, when you create the database, name it with extension.
For e.g. if your database name is MyDB, then write it as **MyDB.db**
This will enable the Open File Icon on sqlite manager on eclipse.

Comment: As @V A mentions, if the database file does not finish with the .db extension, the ICON for opening with SQLite browser wont be enabled.

Answer (score 4):

As from your Screenshot it is clear that your database doesn't have an extension currently.
Therefore it is not allowing to open the database file but if you can see here [image]

You can delete the database from here using the "**-**" option delete both the database and .journal file.

Add .db extension where you are creating the ordersManager database and run the application again.(Remeber to create the database)

when you will again come to DDMS to see your database and click on ordersManager.db file the icon which i have circled will become enabled then click on it and you will be able to read data.

Also you can pull the database from device and use something like [SQLLiteBrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

Answer (score 2):

Here are thr few useful links :

1) [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762389/how-to-view-data-saved-in-android-databasesqlite)

2) [Link 2](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

The mistake that you are doing is that you didn't mention the ".db" extension with your db name. Delete your previous db and name a new db with .db extention i.e. "Sample.db" try it i hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark the database like you did in your screenshot but then you have to click the database icon in the top

also its better to place the plugin in the dropin folder because you haven't loaded it by a url

Answer (score 0):

Try this download SQLite3 manager from this http://sqlitemanager.en.softonic.com/ . And install it.And pull your database (i.e. file.db ) from DDMS to now location and try to open it with using Sqlite3 manager.

And you will be able to see your database contents.

I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

1. **Download** the [Android Sqlite Manager](http://www.coderzheaven.com/android1/com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar) here.
2. Add it to your **eclipse > dropins** Directory.
3. **Restart** eclipse and go to DDMS.
4. Select **.db** file in DDMS Perspective
5. **click** Sqlite Manger icon.

Now you're able to open the **.db** file.