# Can't open database on my phone with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I recently started learning to work with SQLite database and I've created a database just for a test.

I'm now trying to open it with eclipse to see if it works but the "data" folder seems empty. I followed **[these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762565/2454356)** instructions and when I get to step 7, when I'm supposed to open "data" folder, I can't open it. I keep pressing on the data folder and nothing happens.

I have my phone rooted (if that matters).

Comment: Run your app in emulator and extract database file from emulator. You won't be able to access that from device directories listed in Eclipse.

Comment: How do I extract it from emulator? The same way as I tried here?

Comment: Yes. Click Emulator -> your App entries -> File explorer -> data -> data -> databases.