# Android - SQLite Manager is hidden in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am developing a simple database application.

I want to see the inserted data. I have follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762389/how-to-view-data-saved-in-android-databasesqlite) instructions to view the data.

But in eclipse the SQLite manage is hidden. Please let me any idea to show view the data.

[image]

[image: My eclipse window]

Comment: Open the DDMS perspective and select the emultaor, open the path: /data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db and click the db file. The icon will be then enabled

Comment: Hi @DerGolem.. I try like that only. I select my DB. But icon is disabled.

Comment: Yes.. See.. I have add another screenshot for your review.

Comment: OK. Try not to use ALL CAPS. I guess the plugin is case sensitive. Try to make (at least) the extension SMALL CAPS: **.db**

Comment: Ok @Der Golem..!! I will try and let you know..!!

Comment: Hi @Der Golem.. After change 'DB' to 'db' it is working..!! Thank you..!!!

Comment: Funny... I'll put it out as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the DDMS perspective and select the emulator, open the path:   `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db` and click the db file.

The icon will be then enabled

**[UPDATE]**

I noticed you are using ALL CAPS file names (...).
But I guess the plugin is case sensitive.
Try to make (at least) the extension SMALL CAPS: **.db**

Answer (score 3):

Open view Window->Show View->File Explorer.

In this view go to data/data/"your app name"/databases/"your database" This is you database file.

For me, I use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).

[Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/browse-sqlite-data-on-the-android-emulator/), you can finf a good tutorial to know how to use it exactly.

Comment: Hi @Farouk_T.. Thanks for the reply.. Now I view from this only. But I am trying to view from eclipse. That's why I have ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose If you have phone then you can copy the database to sdCard

private static String DB_NAME = "db_name";
    private String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/data/package_name/databases/";

    private void copyToSdCard() throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        String outFileName = "/sdcard/file_name.sqlite";
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        InputStream myInput;

        myInput = new FileInputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

Then using mozila firefox add the add-on sqlitemanager and you can check your db. please replace the package name and db name.
```