# Table not updating on update though returning the opposite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a problem where my sqlite table "views" doesn't update upon a update query.

The views table is constructed as follows, my two foreign keys making up for the identifying primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE views
(description TEXT, 
modulesId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES modules(modulesId),
eventId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES events(eventId),
PRIMARY KEY (modulesId, eventId));
```

Using the following code I attempt, and it would appear, succeed in updating the table, as the returned integer takes the result of 1.

```
private SQLiteDatabase database;    

public void updateViews(String description, int modulesId, int eventId) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MyDatabaseManager.VIEWS_DESCRIPTION, description);
    String where = "modulesId = " + modulesId + " AND eventId = " + eventId;

    int i = database.update(MyDatabaseManager.TABLE_VIEWS, values, where, null);
    }
```

So. int i is returned a 1, indicating that my row is indeed updated. However as I attempt to retrieve the rows I find that the description of the supposedly updated row is still null.

```
public List<Views> getAllViews() {
    List<Views> views = new ArrayList<Views>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MyDatabaseManager.TABLE_VIEWS, allViewsColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Views view = cursorToView(cursor);
        views.add(view);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return views;
}
```

This is true without closing the application.

I have no visible errors in my code, and nor do I seem to be able to make out much of my logcat. Which leads me to believe I have done something fundamentally wrong somewhere in my code. Most likely in code that I haven't posted, but perhaps you can make out where I might have gone wrong.

I am not very proficient at programming but I will do my best to follow any help that I get. Thanks!

Update 1:

That looks promising, inmyth. I will give that a good looking over. Thanks!

```
private Views cursorToView(Cursor cursor) {
    Views view = new Views();
    view.setModuleId(cursor.getLong(0));
    view.setEventId(cursor.getLong(1));
    return view;
}
```

Update 2: Answer

Additionally I had forgotten to update my allViewsColumn with my description column, but that is not a part of this specific question, but could possibly help someone out.

```
private Views cursorToView(Cursor cursor) {
    Views view = new Views();
    view.setModuleId(cursor.getLong(0));
    view.setEventId(cursor.getLong(1));
    view.setViewDescription(cursor.getString(2));
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the update but how the cursor is loaded. I think I need to see cursorToView().

Comment: @inmyth Hi. That looks promising. I will try to work with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. You didn't load the description in cursorToView().

Next time you can read your own database to see if any entry is missing provided you run an emulator. [How to view data saved in android database(SQLite)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762389/how-to-view-data-saved-in-android-databasesqlite)