# How to show sqlite database when i connected with my mobile?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to show sqlite database for that I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762389/how-to-view-data-saved-in-android-databasesqlite) step.
But I'm using my mobile for testing the app. So when I click on 
DBMS -> file explorer -> data 
it doesn't open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is not rooted then we can't access the sqlite database from device in DDMS mode but you can able to copy to SD card by the following code.

```
try
        {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite())
            {
                String currentDBPath = "/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/yourdatabasename";
                String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
                File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists())
                {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```